# How to clear the state of Windows filtering platform?

Tags: windows-firewall, netsh

To troubleshoot firewall I use:

`netsh wfp show state`

this generates xml file for all the dropped packets and firewall state.

the problem is that this file is 13 MB, and it keeps growing each time I run the command.

is there an option to clear the sate of WFP? maybe I should disable something somewhere, but what?

I have only enabled auditing for dropped packets, and my firewall isn't dropping that much, so this xml file should not be that big.

btw. I did try to disable auditing dropped packets, but this will only prevent adding this info to firewall state, but the file is still huge, and full of old data.

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not, however I've learned that this file contains all the filters from all policy stores in addition to audit entries, which means you can reduce it's size by reducing the amount of firewall rules applied to active store. and then also disable all auditing. I didn't test it yet, my file is currently 100MB which is quite worrying.

Comment: That is kind of ridiculous - any program with administrative privileges can add just one rule to block all internet and there is no options to reset WFP state with system tools